# I wanted to update an existing record in asp.net mvc using Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, record

I wanted to check if the `productDiscount` entity is already exist in the database, if it is exist then I wanted to update it. But instead of updating the entity the following code adds a new one. How to solve this problem..

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ProductDiscount(ProductDiscount productDiscount)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var viewModel = new ViewModelProductDiscount()
            {
                Products = _context.Products.ToList()
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        var id = productDiscount.ProductId;
        var disInDb = _context.ProductDiscounts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == id);
        if (disInDb==null)
        {
            _context.ProductDiscounts.Add(productDiscount);
            _context.SaveChanges();              
        }
        else
        {
            _context.ProductDiscounts.Add(disInDb);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Content(disInDb.Id.ToString());
        }


       return RedirectToAction("Products");
    }
```

Comment: What's not working? Any error?

Comment: I want to update the record if the record already exists in the database but instead of updating. it is adding a new record to the database.

Comment: Can you post `ProductDiscount` object

Answer (score 0):

from the `else` block remove `_context.ProductDiscounts.Add(disInDb);` Just map the `productDiscount` values into `disInDb` and then `_context.SaveChanges();`

Like

```
    else
    {        
       disInDb.Name = productDiscount.Name;
       disInDb.Discription = productDiscount.Discription;

       _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know how your `ProductDiscount` object looks like so I will assume your object props but it should give you an idea of how to update the record. Inside your `else` this line `_context.ProductDiscounts.Add(disInDb);` is what is causing the issue. Instead you want to do the following inside the `else` block

```
else
{
   disInDb.DiscountCode = "somecode"; //change this to the correct prop name which needs updating
   disInDb.DiscountProductName = "somename"; //change this to the correct prop name which needs updating

   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying "Instead you want to do the following", I can't follow your argumentation. Rephrase it a bit.